# PHP fopen() returns NULL, always

Tags: php, fopen, freebsd, lighttpd

I'm attempting to open a file for parsing (a binary file), however no matter what fopen() is always returning NULL.

I've ruled out nearly everything to the point where I have a test script with simply:

```
<?php
$idx = fopen('/usr/home/username/web/appname/dev/www/debug/18194001.idx','r');
trigger_error(var_export($idx,true));
exit();
```

The output from trigger_error(var_export()); is:

```
[31-Mar-2013 16:30:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  NULL in /usr/home/username/web/appname/dev/www/debug/ajax.idx.php on line 3
```

No matter what flags I specify for the second fopen() option, I get the same result.

Now, the obvious question is whether or not the file exists, and do I have permissions to read it? The answer to both of those is yes. I've used the relative path and absolute path, both read the file correct. file_get_contents() also reads the file with no issues.

is_readable() and file_exists() both return true

The output of ls -lah for that file is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 username  username  2.0K Mar 30 15:02 18194001.idx
```

Where 'username' matches the username the web server process and PHP (lighttpd and php-fpm) are running under. The parent directory also has read/read/read rights for user/group/all.

I've tried other files, and I've noticed pretty much anything I throw at fopen is returning a NULL value.

Help?

PHP info:

```
PHP 5.4.6 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2012 10:43:19)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v2.0.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
```

Lighttpd info:

```
lighttpd/1.4.31 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Sep  7 2012 15:38:20
```

OS:

```
FreeBSD hostname.hostname.hostname 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #0: Thu Feb 17 02:41:51 UTC 2011     root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

Comment: Do you have safe mode on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully `var_export` a `fopen`ed resource, you can however `var_dump` it:

```
$ php -r 'var_export(fopen("/tmp/a","w+"));'
NULL
$ php -r 'var_dump(fopen("/tmp/a","w+"));'
resource(5) of type (stream)
```

... because `var_export()` is meant to 'restore'  a variable in PHP script, and resources require more setup then possible in instantiating a simple variable. If you want to know whether the `fopen` succeeded, just check it is not `false`.

```
$ php -r 'var_export(fopen("/this/does/not/exist","w+"));'
... some errors...
false
```

In other words, the fact you get `NULL` from a `var_export` means the `fopen` actually was successful.

Comment: ...and that did it. I got an error from fread, so my first instinct was to wrap it with trigger_error(var_export()) - that provided false, so I then wrapped the function before it - which is the fopen. Didn't realize a resource would display null in that, versus what it displays in var_dump(). The more you know, I guess. Thanks!