# fopen doesn't work on files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, fopen

I've made a GCP cloud function in PHP8.1, that connects to GCP cloud storage. I receive a filename to be processed, and the cloud function should open the file, decode it, and send the result to a pub sub.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get `fopen` to work on the file hosted in cloud storage.

I need `fopen` to work, because another package that I'm using to decode AVRO files uses `fopen` to access the file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I've tested `file_get_contents` and that works fine.

I've also tested downloading the file contents as a stream using the cloud storage package, and that works fine as well.

I've also modified the `allow_url_fopen` php setting, but that didn't change anything.

I'm using the `google/cloud-storage` package, version v1.30.2

I'm using the `google/cloud` package, version v0.201.0

```
$bucketName = 'bucket-name';
$filePath = 'file/path/in/bucket';

$this->storageClient->registerStreamWrapper();
$bucket = $this->storageClient->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->object($filePath);

$newGsFilePath = "gs://$bucketName/$filePath";

error_log(file_exists($newGsFilePath)); // logs "1", signifying that the file exists
error_log(file_get_contents($newGsFilePath)); // logs the contents of the file
$fp = fopen($newGsFilePath, "rb"); 
error_log(var_export($fp, true)); // logs "NULL". It should be false according to docs when it fails?
error_log(fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET)); // logs "-1", presumably because $fp is NULL
fclose($fp);

$stream = $object->downloadAsStream();
$contents = '';
while (!$stream->eof()) {
    $contents .= $stream->read(1024);
}

error_log("\$contents: $contents"); // logs the contents of the file
```

Could it be a permissions issue? I'm not the admin of this account, and am fairly new to GCP

Comment: [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) doesn't seem to work with resource pointer. Try to use `print_r($fp, true)` instead of `var_export($fp, true)`.

Comment: Not all streams are seekable. If `$fp` is a valid resource, try to use [stream_get_meta_data()](https://www.php.net/stream_get_meta_data) on `$fp` and see if the `seekable` flag is true.

Comment: Found this very related question and answer, saying that the result of `fopen` can't be `var_export`ed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731744/21638849

So now the question is, why `fseek` is returning -1?

Comment: @KoalaYeung thanks for that comment. It seems that the stream is in fact not seekable. Any ideas on how I can work around that? I'm thinking maybe copy the contents to a "local" file that might be seekable?

Comment: I don't yet understand why you need to `seek($fp, 0)`. From the code you shared, `$fp` was never read so it is already at 0 pos. If you don't need to seek back-and-forth from the file, perhaps you can just use [fread()](https://www.php.net/fread) or "read" to skip through bytes until you get to the target location.

Comment: I appreciate that. My need for `seek` to work is because another library uses it internally. Copying the file locally by doing `file_put_contents(file_get_contents())` worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

The files opened from a Google Cloud Storage are not seekable, that's why `seek($fp, 0)` returns -1.

The file can be transformed into a seekable file by copying its contents into a local file, using

```
file_put_contents('new/local/path/to.file', file_get_contents($newGsFilePath));
```

I would recommend deleting the file after you are done with it.

Thanks to @KoalaYoung for helping me come to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manage an extra file (or if you want to work within memory), you may try this:

```php
$bucketName = 'bucket-name';
$filePath = 'file/path/in/bucket';

$this->storageClient->registerStreamWrapper();
$bucket = $this->storageClient->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->object($filePath);

$newGsFilePath = "gs://$bucketName/$filePath";

$fp = fopen($newGsFilePath, 'rb');
$cache = fopen('php://temp', 'wb+');
stream_copy_to_stream($fp, $cache);
fclose($fp);
rewind($cache);

// Use $cache instead of $fp
// ...
// ...
```

The ["php://temp" read-write stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory) would be created in-memory until it is larger than 2MB (or override the maxmemory like this: `php://temp/maxmemory:16MB`). If it is bigger, PHP will create and manage it as a temp file.